# I try to scrape a website, and I keep getting 404 error

Tags: python, google-chrome, curl, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to **scrape** this website:

`https://www.nadlan.gov.il`

It is a website in Israel, that shows data on historical real-estate deals.

In the search box, you can search in free text to what city/neighborhood you want to see the historical deals.

It supports only Hebrew, so I type: שכונת גבעת מרדכי, ירושלים

Which means Givat Mordechai neighborhood, Jerusalem.

I track the network tab on chrome, and I see that the function that returns the actual data (grid) is `GetAssetsAndDeals` - and it returns a JSON with all the required data.

So I copy the CURL, and I convert it to Python code, using `https://curl.trillworks.com/` - and it returns to me this code:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '_ga': 'GA1.3.584052889.1509031917',
    '_gid': 'GA1.3.66244842.1510507506',
    'keshet-client-token': 'dvVFgVcuJrTgXPx+w9KtJktxk2wVZXGU1EfZ+3uBhMUYr9ZNWFKIBogGUbb8GjCRqetT2Vf0RRap26mkrYNDp8Nf0ZntyB3fYPNn65i9lrzVYU7bZpI79aqu/D9pYlm4aJj76C5fGsU+ncV5IsysqlqCa0ihRtWhncW6xMxr0l7H4L2OqPk2A5rSCHyAbzdn',
}

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.nadlan.gov.il',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nadlan.gov.il/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

data = '^{^\\^MoreAssestsType^\\^:0,^\\^FillterRoomNum^\\^:0,^\\^GridDisplayType^\\^:0,^\\^ResultLable^\\^:^\\^^\u05E9^\u05DB^\u05D5^\u05E0^\u05EA'

requests.post('https://www.nadlan.gov.il/KeshetAnnan.REST/Main/GetAssestAndDeals', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

But when I run this code on Python - I get 404 error!

I guess it has something to do with the encoding, but I'm not sure what I should change...

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the real request, you are not sending the complete JSON data necessary to get the response. From the network logs, the data to send in the POST endpoint can be retrieved using :

GET https://www.nadlan.gov.il/Nadlan.REST/Main/GetDataByQuery?query=CONTENT

This gives the complete JSON sent in the next POST request :

POST https://www.nadlan.gov.il/Nadlan.REST/Main/GetAssestAndDeals

But for some reason, you have to change the `PageNo` field because it's set to `0` by default which gives a 404 status code. Setting it to something > 0 seems to be working.

Here is the full script :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json

data = requests.get(
    'https://www.nadlan.gov.il/Nadlan.REST/Main/GetDataByQuery',
    params={'query': 'שכונת גבעת מרדכי, ירושלים'}
)

json_data = data.json()
json_data['PageNo'] = 1

r = requests.post(
    'https://www.nadlan.gov.il/Nadlan.REST/Main/GetAssestAndDeals', 
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }, 
    data = json.dumps(json_data)
)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

I guess you will want to modify the `json_data` intermediary result to adjust the position or other fields

Comment: for some reason, it's not working now for me. 
Does it work for you?
Did they change anything? it is so weird...

Comment: I've tried just now and it seems the base url for the rest api changed from to `Nadlan.REST` instead of `KeshetAnnan.REST`. Don't know if this is an update or if this is intended

Comment: I tried to figure out how did you understand that GetAssestAndDeals is using the data from GetDataByQuery? Can you please tell me what tool did you use? did you just use the Chrome developer tool or did you use a more advanced tool? Thanks!

Comment: @BinyaminEven yes I just used network tabs in Chrome developer tool & found out the input data for `GetAssestAndDeals` was very similar to the result from `GetDataByQuery`. IIRC some trial & error were necessary to find that the field `PageNo` should be set to something > 0 since `GetDataByQuery` used to return `PageNo=0`. Also when you go to network tab : click on request / Copy / Copy as cURL is useful for testing